# Asp.net Telerik Radsearchbox not filter properly

Tags: asp.net, telerik, filtering

I'm using radsearchbox as a control in my site for search trough db. I used a object data source as radsearchbox's datasource. the aspx code is here:

```
  <telerik:RadSearchBox ID="RadSearchBox1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceSearch" 
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" 
   EmptyMessage="search here" 
     Skin="Silk" MinFilterLength="3">
  </telerik:RadSearchBox>

  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceSearch" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="detail" TypeName="InStore">
  </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And detail function is:

```
 Function detail() As List(Of info)
    Dim All_info As New List(Of info)
      Dim _inf As New info
            _inf.ID = 1
            _inf.Name = "aaa"
             All_info.Add(_inf)
    Dim _inf2 As New info
    _inf2.ID = 100
   _inf2.Name = "bbb"
    All_info.Add(_inf2)
     Return All_info
End Function
```

And when I typed any text in radsearchbox, It displays all items in the list.("aaa" and "bbb")
why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it will display everything in the list, because in **SelectMethod** you are setting the function **detail()**. The function detail is returning the whole list.

To overcome this you can use the **OnSearch** event handler of the radseachbox or simply use the **Linq** to filter the result and then return the filtered list.

I don't know about your scenario, but this is my guess. try this code

```
Protected Function Search(sender As Object, e As SearchBoxEventArgs) As List(Of info)
    Dim searchtext As String = e.text
    Dim filteredinfo As New List(Of info)()
    Dim searchresult As New List(Of info)()
    filteredinfo = detail()
    searchresult = filteredinfo.where(Function(res) res.Contains(searchtext))
    searchresult += filteredinfo.where(Function(res1) res1.Contains(searchtext))
    Return searchresult
End Function
```

And dont forgot to paste this code in **OnSearch** event handler of radsearchbox.